# Objective C: Move local core data store to icloud and vice versa

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I'm having problems with this and read now several tutorials and also examples in one book, which however suggested more a deep copy which is too complicated for me. This iCloud stuff is anyway confusing. Did I get it right with this:

User enabling iCloud in app:
- Try to copy local store to icloud
- Deleting local store

User disabling iCloud in app:
- Try to copy store to local
- Remove ubiquitous content
- Remove local copy of icloud

Do I miss anything?

Extra questions: How can I "block" the app during copying and where should I place this "blocking" code?

This would be my code:

```
- (bool)moveStoreToICloud {
    NSLog(<#NSString * _Nonnull format, ...#>)(@" called");
    return [self moveStoreFileToICloud:self.store delete:YES backup:YES];
}

- (bool)moveStoreFileToICloud:(NSURL*)fileURL delete:(bool)shouldDelete backup:(bool)shouldBackup {
    NSLog(@" called");

    // Always make a backup of the local store before migrating to iCloud
    if (shouldBackup)
        [self backupLocalStore];

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *migrationPSC = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.model];

    // Open the existing local store using the original options
    NSDictionary *options =
    @{
      NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES
      ,NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES
      ,NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey:ubiquitousContentNameKey
      //,NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey:@"ChangeLogs" // Optional since iOS7
      };
    id sourceStore = [migrationPSC addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:fileURL options:options error:nil];

    if (!sourceStore) {
        NSLog(@" failed to add old store");
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        NSLog(@" Successfully added store to migrate");

        bool moveSuccess = NO;
        NSError *error;

        NSLog(@" About to migrate the store...");
        // Now migrate the store using the iCloud options
        id migrationSuccess = [migrationPSC migratePersistentStore:sourceStore toURL:[_iCloudStore URL] options:options withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

        if (migrationSuccess) {
            moveSuccess = YES;
            NSLog(@"store successfully migrated");
            // Now delete the local file
            if (shouldDelete) {
                NSLog(@" deleting local store");
                [self destroyAllLocalDataForThisApplication];
            } else {
                NSLog(@" not deleting local store");
            }

            [self resetCoreData];
            [self setupCoreData];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomethingChanged"
                                                                object:nil];
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to migrate store: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
            return FALSE;
        }

    }
    return FALSE;
}
/*! Moves an iCloud store to local by migrating the iCloud store to a new local store and then removes the store from iCloud.

 Note that even if it fails to remove the iCloud files it deletes the local copy.  User may need to clean up orphaned iCloud files using a Mac!

 @return Returns YES of file was migrated or NO if not.
 */
- (bool)moveStoreToLocal {
    NSLog(@"moveStoreToLocal called");

    // Lets use the existing PSC
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *migrationPSC = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.model];

    // Open the store
    NSDictionary *options =
    @{
      NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES
      ,NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES
      ,NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey:ubiquitousContentNameKey
      //,NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey:@"ChangeLogs" // Optional since iOS7
      };
    id sourceStore = [migrationPSC addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[_iCloudStore URL] options:options error:nil];

    if (!sourceStore) {

        NSLog(@" failed to add old store");
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        NSLog(@" Successfully added store to migrate");

        bool moveSuccess = NO;
        NSError *error;

        NSLog(@" About to migrate the store...");
        id migrationSuccess = [migrationPSC migratePersistentStore:sourceStore toURL:[_store URL] options:options withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

        if (migrationSuccess) {
            moveSuccess = YES;
            NSLog(@"store successfully migrated");
            // Now delete the local file
            [self destroyAlliCloudDataForThisApplication];

            [self resetCoreData];
            [self setupCoreData];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomethingChanged"
                                                                object:nil];
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to migrate store: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
            return FALSE;
        }

    }

    return TRUE;
}


#pragma mark - ICLOUD RESET
- (void)destroyAllLocalDataForThisApplication {

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[_store URL] path]]) {
        NSLog(@"Skipped destroying content, _store.URL is %@",[[_store URL] path]);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n **** Destroying ALL local content for this application, this could take a while...  **** \n\n\n\n\n\n");

    [self removeAllStoresFromCoordinator:_coordinator];
    [self removeAllStoresFromCoordinator:_seedCoordinator];
    _coordinator = nil;
    _seedCoordinator = nil;

    NSError *error;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:_storeURL error:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Local store successfully removed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"\n\n **** FAILED to destroy this application's iCloud content at URL (%@) **** \n%@\n",[_store URL],error);
    }
}


- (void)destroyAlliCloudDataForThisApplication {

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[_iCloudStore URL] path]]) {
        NSLog(@"Skipped destroying iCloud content, _iCloudStore.URL is %@",[[_iCloudStore URL] path]);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n **** Destroying ALL iCloud content for this application, this could take a while...  **** \n\n\n\n\n\n");

    [self removeAllStoresFromCoordinator:_coordinator];
    [self removeAllStoresFromCoordinator:_seedCoordinator];
    _coordinator = nil;
    _seedCoordinator = nil;

    NSDictionary *options =
    @{
      NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey:ubiquitousContentNameKey
      //,NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey:@"ChangeLogs" // Optional since iOS7
      };
    NSError *error;
    if ([NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:[_iCloudStore URL]
                                                                             options:options
                                                                               error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n");
        NSLog(@"*        This application's iCloud content has been destroyed        *");
        NSLog(@"* On ALL devices, please delete any reference to this application in *");
        NSLog(@"*  Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage > Show All  *");
        NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:[_iCloudStore URL] error:&error]
    } else {
        NSLog(@"\n\n **** FAILED to destroy this application's iCloud content at URL (%@) **** \n%@\n",[_iCloudStore URL],error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new app, rethink your approach. Use CloudKit, or Azure, or Firebase.

iCloud Core Data never worked reliably. Thankfully Apple now realizes this. `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey` is marked as deprecated as of iOS 10/macOS 12.12, as are the other iCloud Core Data symbols.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a new app :/

Comment: What is changing? Are you adding cloud sync to an existing Core Data app?

Comment: Exactly. So far it was only local and now I would like to add the option for users to move it ti icloud (and back if they want). So basically it should just move the coredata from local->icloud and back

Comment: Many great programmers have dashed themselves to pieces upon the rocks of iCloud Core Data. It seriously never worked correctly and robustly. It's now deprecated. Pick a different back end, per second sentence of my answer.

Comment: But I don't get it...is iCloud really deprecated?! Nobody uses it anymore?

Comment: Correct. Take a look at newly updated https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/, which walks you through using CloudKit to implement Core Data sync.